# Acrylic paint on polypropylene PP

Tags: bond, polymers, plastics

I have bought a set of [polypropylene (PP) test tubes](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01AW6TB24/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) that I wish to paint with acrylic to achieve the same effect as the following image:

[image: test tubes coated in acrylic]

Can anyone recommend a process I can apply to the test tubes (in a home setting) or type of paint (acrylic not necessary) that will bind and last and allow me to achieve a similar effect as is pictured above. My main worry is that it may bind but a year or two later will begin to flake off.

Any primer must be completely transparent.

Apologies if this is not the typical question asked here I initially posted this in arts and crafts but then realised this is less about art than it is to do with the properties of polypropylene and someone here is likely to have a greater expertise in that area.

**EDIT:** As far as I am aware the reason acrylics don't bond well to PP is due to the low surface energy (LSE) of PP. I have found some products that purport to raise the surface energy of PP to be used with adhesives but before I go ahead and purchase them I would love for someone with more knowledge to confirm that this is likely to work. For example:

[Techsil® Clear Cyanoacrylate Primer 77](http://www.techsil.co.uk/media/pdf/TDS/TECY15102-tds.pdf) or [LOCTITE® 770™](http://tds.henkel.com/tds5/Studio/ShowPDF/SF%20770-EN?pid=SF%20770&format=MTR&subformat=REAC&language=EN&plant=WERCS)

Comment: Paint the **insides**. Acrylic paint does not adhere well to polypropylene, and would soon flake off the outside. Stopper the tubes to last longer. If there is much thermal cycling (e.g. left outdoors), it may still flake somewhat.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks I intend to achieve the effect by dripping it inside the tubes and then stopper the ends and seal them in polyurethane. I wonder would the amount of paint affect how quickly it flakes?